# Why p in "int q[],p[];" is a 2d array?

Tags: java

Following are the different ways of valid array declaration

`int p[]` or `int []p` or `int[] p` and suppose we write `int x,y` then both x and y are of type integers but when i write `int []q, p[];` why compiler says that `p` is an 2d array

please see the code below

```
public class some {
    int []q, p[];
    void x() {  
        p=new int[10][3];// this is valid
        //p=new int[10];// compiler expects p as 2d array
        q=new int[10];  
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: [array in java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note the difference, in Java, when you write:

```
int[] q, p[];
```

Then `q` is `int[]` and `p` is `int[][]`

Because it's like writing:

```
int[] q;
int[] p[];
```

But when you write

```
int q[], p[];
```

Then `q` is `int[]` and `p` is `int[]`

That's why you should be careful with that.

Java allows `int array[]` just to make C programmers feel happy :)

Another thing to note:

```
int[] happyArray1, happyArray2;
int happyArray[], happyInt;
```

---

**Clarification**:

When you write `int a, b` then it's clear that `a` and `b` are both `int`s. Think about it this way: You "apply" the `int` on both `a` and `b`.

But when you have `int[] a, b[]`, then you "apply" `int[]` on both `a` and `b[]`! So you get that `a` is `int[]`, but `b` is `int[][]`.

Comment: but my question is int []q, p[]

Comment: @javaBeginner I know, I think I explained that..

Comment: but you explained for int[] q, p[]

Comment: yes i know both are same as I have posted in the question valid array declaration

Comment: @javaBeginner That's valid too. They are the same.

Comment: you said **int[] q, p[];** can be written as **int[] q;
int[] p[];** I did not get how.Is it just an assumption or any oracle docs or how?

Comment: That's because when you write `int[] q, p` then both `q` and `p` are `int[]`, but when you write `int[] q, p[]` then `q` is `int[]` and `p[]` is as the left side.. it's `p[]` and `[]` from `int[]`, so it'll be "`int[][]`".

Comment: Now i completely understood so +1

Answer (score 10):

```
int []q, p[];
```

This can be written as

```
int[] q;
int[] p[]; // This is effectively a 2d array and that is why compiler gives that error.
```

That is why you need to follow any 1 style of declaring arrays.

**Style 1** : `int[] arr; // This is the general preference is Java`

**Style 2** : `int arr[]; // I remember using this style when working in C++`

and not combine both, which is most likely going to get you confused. And as [Jon rightly commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419968/is-p-int-q-p-is-a-2d-array/19420018#comment28788901_19420018), always follow the first style as its the recommended one.

Comment: But please don't follow the second style anyway - it's just a throwback to C, and isn't recommended.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Updated the answer with your advice!:)